# SAS: Read File scattered across lines

Tags: file-io, sas

I have data in the .txt file as:

```
VALUE   ADM_LN2G                                                            
               1     = 'ENGLISH'                                            
               2     = 'FRENCH'                                             
               3     = 'ARABIC'                                             
               4     = 'CHINESE'                                            
               5     = 'CREE'                                               
               6     = 'GERMAN'                                             
               7     = 'GREEK'                                              
                   ;                                                        
VALUE   ADM_LNG                                                             
              24     = 'INUKTITUT'                                          
              90     = 'OTHER'                                              
              96     = 'NOT APPLICABLE'                                     
              97     = 'DON''T KNOW'                                        
              98     = 'REFUSAL'                                            
              99     = 'NOT STATED'                                         
                   ;
```

.
.
.
.
I want to separate out each value in different dataset.
Output expected:
Dataset 1 : ADM_LN2G
   VALUE   ADM_LN2G
                   1     = 'ENGLISH'
                   2     = 'FRENCH'
                   3     = 'ARABIC'
                   4     = 'CHINESE'
                   5     = 'CREE'
                   6     = 'GERMAN'
                   7     = 'GREEK'
                       ; 
Dataset 2: ADM_LNG

```
VALUE   ADM_LNG                                                             
              24     = 'INUKTITUT'                                          
              90     = 'OTHER'                                              
              96     = 'NOT APPLICABLE'                                     
              97     = 'DON''T KNOW'                                        
              98     = 'REFUSAL'                                            
              99     = 'NOT STATED' 
                   ;
```

etc.

For every VALUE there is ";" at the end.
Please help!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have SAS?  Why not just run the code and export the generated formats using PROC format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is valid code for creating SAS formats then you can get at the data by letting SAS create the formats.

```
proc format lib=work.newformats;
%include "source file";
run;
```

Then use PROC FORMAT to export the formats to a data set.

```
proc format lib=work.newformats cntlout=WANT(keep=fmtname start label);
run;
```